# Lambda and eval doesn't working inside a function

Tags: python, lambda, eval

I am a newbie to python and I will really appreciate your help in my following problem.

Problem:

I am working a keyword matching on a Dataframe, I did try the code in Jupyter notebook where it is working perfectly fine. However, the same code is not working in Visual Code. Both Jupyter Notebook and VS Code are running on the same python environment.

Input Dataframe:

```
note
-----------------
I have a kayak
I have a jet-ski
I have a canoe
I have a jetski
```

Code that does the magic:

```
def extract():
    keywords = ['kayak','jetski']

    kayak = re.compile(r'.*(pin.pad|pinpad).*')
    jetski= re.compile(r'.*(jetski|jet.ski).*')

    for i in keywords:
        df[i] = df['note'].apply(lambda x: bool(eval((i)).match(x)))
```

I did receive the expected output in Jupyter however, Visual Code states the following error.

```
File "xyz.py", line 8, in <lambda>
    df[i] = df['note'].apply(lambda x: bool(eval((i)).match(x)))
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'kayak' is not defined
```

Expected Output:

```
note                  kayak       jetski
-----------------------------------------
I have a kayak         True        False
I have a jet-ski       False       True
I have a canoe         False       False
I have a jetski        False       True
```

Please let me know if this has already been answered or if further information is required. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `eval` here. Just define a `dict` that maps "kayak" and "jets" to the appropriate objects.

```
def extract():
    keywords = {
       'kayak': re.compile(r'.*(pin.pad|pinpad).*'),
       'jetski': re.compile(r'.*(jetski|jet.ski).*')
    }

    for keyword, regex in keywords.items():
        df[keyword] = df['note'].apply(lambda x: bool(regex.match(x)))
```

The problem was that your two variables did not exist in the local scope of the function created by the lambda expression, but they weren't in the global scope either. An ordinary `dict` lookup is far simpler than getting a call to `eval` correct.

Comment: Thanks that helps! and a dictionary is a good idea in need. However, I have some dependency on that list further down the program. And also I am curious, how can we solve the program using the list itself.

I believe the issue is because of the lambda function, as I have another loop immediately after where eval() is working perfectly.